# Intersections and unions of families of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

This is a homework question but I have no clue where to get started or how to attempt this. I know how to do this if A was a set of open sets but not sure about closed sets.

Any help would be appreciated!

> Let A be a nonempty collection of closed subsets of the reals
>
> a) Prove that the intersection of all the sets in A is closed.
>
> b) If A is a finite collection, prove that the union of all the sets in A is closed.

Also, why does part b) require the assumption that A is a finite collection?

Comment: what definition of "closed" are you working with? And for your last question, just look at $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [1/n,1]$$

Comment: Just use De Morgan's laws.

Comment: I'm working with the definition where a set is closed if the complement of that set is open. Also, thanks for the last answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part (a) is very straightforward.
Recall:

- A set is **closed** if and only if for every point outside that set, there is an open ball around that point *not* contained in the set.  (I.e., the complement of the set is open).

Therefore, consider the intersection of closed sets,
$\bigcap_{i \in I} C_i$.  $I$ is an index set of arbitrary size.
Now consider a point $x$ outside the intersection.
What does it mean for $x$ to be outside the intersection?  It means there is some $i$ such that $x \not \in C_i$.  Well then, you have that there is a ball around $x$, $B(x, \epsilon)$, that is also not in $C_i$.  But then by definition of the intersection this ball is not in $\bigcap_{i \in I} C_i$ either.

For part (b), such an argument doesn't quite work.  Notice what happens...

Consider an intersection of closed sets $\bigcup_{i \in I} C_i$.
A point $x$ outside this intersection must lie outside $C_i$ for *every* $i$.
That means you can find $B(x, \epsilon_i)$ not contained in $C_i$ for every $i$.
But in order to conclude there is a ball $B(x, \epsilon)$ not conatined in *any* $C_i$, you need to be able to take the minimum of all the $\epsilon_i$s and have it be positive, which you can only do if there are finitely many of them.

For a counterexample to the infinite case, use the classic $C_i = \left[\tfrac1i, 1\right]$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$.